# Flutter immutable class?

Tags: annotations, immutability, flutter

IDE recognised [`StoreWatcher`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_flux/blob/master/lib/src/store_watcher.dart) Flutter Widget as immutable. Where is that `@immutable` annotation? It is not in the store_watcher.dart source code.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The annotation is from the [meta](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/meta) package

The [docs](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/meta/1.1.1/meta/immutable-constant.html) say

> Used to annotate a class C. Indicates that C and all subtypes of C
>   must be immutable.
>
> A class is immutable if all of the instance fields of the class,
>   whether defined directly or inherited, are final.
>
> Tools, such as the analyzer, can provide feedback if
>
> the annotation is associated with anything other than a class, or a
>   class that has this annotation or extends, implements or mixes in a
>   class that has this annotation is not immutable.

Not all annotation cause the expected feedback yet.
Some might need to enable [linter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/linter) rules.
For some it might only planned yet to be supported eventually by the analyzer or the linter.

Comment: There is no such annotation in [the source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_flux/blob/master/lib/src/store_watcher.dart).

Comment: Class `StoreWatcher` extends `StatefulWidget`, which extends `Widget` which has the `@immutable` annotation. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f2ab841ac429a7e50f4efdf8ba2668c48560ed93/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L431

Comment: arr.. alright. I never saw that `@immutable` in notification on many `StatefulWidget`, which must happen to be immutable all along.

Comment: Perhaps support for `@immutable` was only added recently.